# Automatic Rollbacks SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting Rollbacks automatically.
Here is my code:

```
@socketio.on('update2')
def update_table_infocorp(trigger):
    checknotprocess = Infocorp.query.filter(Infocorp.Procesado == False)

    for row in checknotprocess:
        getidentityuser = Usuarios.query.filter(Usuarios.id_user == row.id_user).first()
        getidentityconsulta = Consolidado.query.filter(Consolidado.id_user == row.id_user and
                                                       (Consolidado.numdocumento == getidentityuser.numdocumento)).first()
        if not getidentityconsulta:
            # print("No se encontro la consulta relacionada al usuario.")
            test = True
        else:
            sentinelresult = getsentinel(getidentityuser.tipodocumento, getidentityuser.numdocumento, row.id_consulta,
                                         getidentityconsulta.solicitudes_id)
            print(getidentityconsulta.solicitudes_id)
            print(getidentityuser.tipodocumento)
            if sentinelresult == True:
                continue
            else:
                print("Ocurrio un error")

    resultadoquery = Infocorp.query.filter(Infocorp.Procesado == True)
    datatransform = InfocorpSchema(many=True)
    datatransformresult = datatransform.dump(resultadoquery)
    emit('nuevatableinfocorp', datatransformresult, broadcast=True)
```

And those are my logs:

[image]

I hope you will be able to help me because it is affecting other systems that use the same database.

Comment: If you don't `commit` your sessions, they will `ROLLBACK` when they are closed.

Comment: Hi @snakecharmerb in this case, where should I add the commit ?